# HTML CSS Box Animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am having multiple boxes and I just want to give an effect which looks like they are on top of each other.

[image]

I am not able to make that card or stack effect(I thought with box-shadow I can achieve but failed).

[image]

I am not getting an exact idea about how we can achieve it.
Kindly help me with your ideas, I will really appreciate it.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
}

.p-box {
    height: 100%;
}

.c-box {
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem rgba(0,0,0, .8);
}

.c-box--1 { 
    background: purple;
    animation: box-height-anim .2s linear .5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.c-box--2 { 
    background: red;
    animation: box-height-anim .2s linear .7s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.c-box--3 { 
    background: green; 
    animation: box-height-anim .2s linear .9s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.c-box--4 { 
    background: blue;
    animation: box-height-anim .2s linear 1.1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes box-height-anim {
    0% {
        height: 0;
    }

    100% {
        height: 25%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="p-box">
        <div class="c-box c-box--1"></div>
        <div class="c-box c-box--2"></div>
        <div class="c-box c-box--3"></div>
        <div class="c-box c-box--4"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your requirement is to give an effect that looks like cards are on top of each other, you need to play with the "z-index" property. Here is what I have done -

```
position: relative; // Added for c-box class
z-index: 9999; // for the card which has to be on top c-box-1, 999 for second, 99 for third and 9 for last card
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
}

.p-box {
    height: 100%;
}

.c-box {
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem rgba(0,0,0, .8);
  position: relative;
}

.c-box--1 { 
    background: purple;
    animation: box-height-anim .2s linear .5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.c-box--2 { 
    background: red;
    animation: box-height-anim .2s linear .7s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  z-index: 999;
}

.c-box--3 { 
    background: green; 
    animation: box-height-anim .2s linear .9s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  z-index: 99;
}

.c-box--4 { 
    background: blue;
    animation: box-height-anim .2s linear 1.1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes box-height-anim {
    0% {
        height: 0;
    }

    100% {
        height: 25%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="p-box">
        <div class="c-box c-box--1"></div>
        <div class="c-box c-box--2"></div>
        <div class="c-box c-box--3"></div>
        <div class="c-box c-box--4"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `position:relative` and a `z-index` on each box:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
}

.p-box {
    height: 100%;
}

.c-box {
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem rgba(0,0,0, .8);
    position: relative;
}

.c-box--1 { 
    z-index: 10;
    background: purple;
    animation: box-height-anim .2s linear .5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.c-box--2 { 
    z-index: 9;
    background: red;
    animation: box-height-anim .2s linear .7s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.c-box--3 { 
    z-index: 8;
    background: green; 
    animation: box-height-anim .2s linear .9s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.c-box--4 { 
    z-index: 7;
    background: blue;
    animation: box-height-anim .2s linear 1.1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes box-height-anim {
    0% {
        height: 0;
    }

    100% {
        height: 25%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="p-box">
        <div class="c-box c-box--1"></div>
        <div class="c-box c-box--2"></div>
        <div class="c-box c-box--3"></div>
        <div class="c-box c-box--4"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

HI man i don't realy understand what kind animation you want to make exactly but i solve your problem with that simple way (there is many way to make that goodLuck) ("_") :

```
#Css:
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
}

.p-box {
    height: 90%;
    width: 40%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    transition: ease-in 1s all;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.c-box {
    color: rgb(4, 238, 255);
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: .8rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.c-box:hover {
    z-index: 12;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: ease-in .2s all;
}

.c-box--1 {
    position: relative;
    background: purple;
    height: 25%;
    z-index: 4;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 5px black);
}

.c-box--2 {
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    height: 25%;
    z-index: 3;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 5px black);
}

.c-box--3 {
    position: relative;
    background: green;
    height: 25%;
    z-index: 2;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 5px black);
}

.c-box--4 {
    position: relative;
    background: yellow;
    height: 25%;
    z-index: 1;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 5px black);
}
#HTML :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./aniStack.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="p-box">
        <div class="c-box c-box--1">Home</div>
        <div class="c-box c-box--2">Services</div>
        <div class="c-box c-box--3">Work</div>
        <div class="c-box c-box--4">Contact</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```